# Eclipse CDT ELF Parser unnable to parse debug file

Tags: parsing, elf, eclipse-cdt, objdump, relocation

**TL;DR**

CDT ELF parser and ObjDump cannot parse my relocatable file, but both work properly with Executable File. I wonder if they are related.

ObjDump has wrong abbrev offsets, CDT parser throws *BufferUnderflowException*

**The Problem**

I'm working with Eclipse CDT ELF Parser in order to extract variable informations from my output files. With my exectuble files, it works perfectly. But with a relocatable file, it has problems to read it, but only **after a certain point**.

**Edit:** *It seems the buffer underflow is not really the problem, but a consequence of data misinterpretation. 
Still testing to see how it is processing the file. I'll post more later*

**Analysis**

At first I thought the dwarf section must be corrupted. Using ObjDump, the output file is incomplete with several errors. It actually only shows the types, but with wrong abbreviation numbers and **offsets**.

The log message:

$ C:\MinGW\bin\objdump.exe --dwarf %MYFILE% > %MYFILE%_objdump.txt

```
C:\MinGW\bin\objdump.exe: Warning: DIE at offset 0x1a9 refers to abbreviation number 8020 which does not exist
C:\MinGW\bin\objdump.exe: Warning: DIE at offset 0x1a9 refers to abbreviation number 8020 which does not exist
C:\MinGW\bin\objdump.exe: Warning: Unable to load/parse the .debug_info section, so cannot interpret the .debug_loc section.
C:\MinGW\bin\objdump.exe: Warning: Unable to load/parse the .debug_info section, so cannot interpret the .debug_ranges section.
```

Using readelf, however, it can read it perfectly, with all the sections and symbols. Regarding the other binaries, the readelf and the objdump outputs are the same.

In the debug_info with objdump I have for example:

```
Compilation Unit @ offset 0x170:
  Length:        0x7dc (32-bit)
  Version:       3
  Abbrev Offset: 0x0
  Pointer Size:  4

<0><17b>: Abbrev Number: 1 (DW_TAG_compile_unit)
   <17c>   DW_AT_producer    : (indirect string, offset: 0x0): object
   <180>   DW_AT_language    : 4    (C++)
   <181>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x0): object
   <185>   DW_AT_comp_dir    : (indirect string, offset: 0x0): object
   <189>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x0
   <18d>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0x0
   <191>   DW_AT_stmt_list   : 0x0

<1><195>: Abbrev Number: 2 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
   <196>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x704): OK
   <19a>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 0
   <19b>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 0
   <19c>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x69050403
   <1a0>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0x400746e
   <1a4>   DW_AT_frame_base  : 0 byte block:    ()
   <1a5>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0x2000170>
<2><1a9>: Abbrev Number: 8020
```

while with readelf

```
Compilation Unit @ offset 0x170:
  Length:        0x7dc (32-bit)
  Version:       3
  Abbrev Offset: 0xdb
  Pointer Size:  4

<0><17b>: Abbrev Number: 1 (DW_TAG_compile_unit)   
   <17c>   DW_AT_producer    : (indirect string, offset: 0x3c1): GNU C++ 4.8.1 -mlittle-endian -march=armv7-a -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=softfp -mapcs-frame -mlong-calls -gdwarf-3 -ansi -fno-zero-initialized-in-bss    
   <180>   DW_AT_language    : 4    (C++)
   <181>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x192): C:/[...]
   <185>   DW_AT_comp_dir    : (indirect string, offset: 0x452): C:\[...]
   <189>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x50
   <18d>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0x204
   <191>   DW_AT_stmt_list   : 0x4d

<1><195>: Abbrev Number: 2 (DW_TAG_base_type)
   <196>   DW_AT_byte_size   : 4
   <197>   DW_AT_encoding    : 7    (unsigned)
   <198>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x2a0): long unsigned int
<1><19c>: Abbrev Number: 3 (DW_TAG_base_type)
```

In the second compilation unit, ObjDump didn't change the *abbrev Offset* and therefore it is using the abbrev numbers from the first compilation unity. It means it is interpreting the next values as attribues of a different type - where it should be a base type, it reads as a subprogram.

Another important fact is that this firmware has dynamic allocation, unlike all the other ones that worked.

```
ELF Header:
Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Class:                             ELF32
Data:                              2's complement, little endian
Version:                           1 (current)
OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
ABI Version:                       0
Type:                              REL (Relocatable file)
Machine:                           ARM
Version:                           0x1
Entry point address:               0x0
Start of program headers:          0 (bytes into file)
Start of section headers:          18150404 (bytes into file)
Flags:                             0x5000000, Version5 EABI
Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
Size of program headers:           0 (bytes)
Number of program headers:         0
Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
Number of section headers:         1636
Section header string table index: 1633
```

I know "objdump sees an ELF file through a BFD filter" while "the readelf program does not link against the BFD library". However, I couldn't find any relation between this and CDT ELF parser, though the problems points in this direction.

**Questions**

Well, it's a very dense problem with one thing linked to another, so I have a lot of questions. But feel free to answer only one, or half. Or even give me ideas about what to test.

- What and why is it happening?
- Can't ObjDump parse relocations(if the problem is there)?
- Does ObjDump and CDT have libraries in common (from gcc maybe)?
- How the readelf parses it's file? Is it possible to replicate it?

**Edit**

Because it was only with one of my elf files, and a very complex firmware, it is difficult to replicate it into a *[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)*. But if you have an idea how I can give more information, please tell me.

Comment: Is there any chance of a [MCVE] for this issue? I am intrigued but I don't have enough to start with.

Comment: Hi @Jonah-graham, I found it very difficult to do a minimal exemple, mostly because I don't have a way to recompilate a minimal firmware in the same environment. What I did was to illustrate with the outcomes of the tools, I hope it helps.

Comment: sadly I am unlikely to be able to help fully. Hopefully someone else will be. If it was me, I would load up both readelf and objdump in a debugger to understand why they are seeing things differently. The other thing I note from your examples is that you are building for ARM, but are not using the ARM specific objdump/readelf. You may have more luck with arm-none-eabi-objcopy (or whatever it is called in your case) especially if it is a newer version. There are pre-built tools kept up to date here https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded. AFAIK the MinGW tools are not really up to date anymore.

Comment: Finally, if you have luck with up to date objdump, you may have simply exposed a bug in the Eclipse CDT code, if so, please raise a bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT

Comment: I report my experience here in case someone stumbles upon the same problem. I got exactly the same Exception thrown by the CDT DwarfParser. It turned out the CDT DwarfParser (I am using CDT 10.7)  is not compatible with DWARF5, and I was using GCC11 to compile, which by default generates debug information in DWARF5. Long story short, I recompile my project using the compiler option `-gdwarf-3` and the error disappeared. I performed a full debug on the CDT code to solve this issue, if you are interested I can give more details.